# How do you grant "write" permissions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Having trouble granting permissions on a text file to the "Everyone" group in PowerShell. The text file is inside the folder "Temp". How can I fix my code?

This is for a lab assignment that I'm doing via VM instance in the Google cloud console. The directory is C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt.

```
Icals C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt\ /grant "Everyone:(w)"
```

I'm expecting to see "Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files", but I am getting "invalid parameter".

Comment: I can see you've got an errant trailing backslash on your file path, ``C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt\``, at the least.  Though I also see you refer to it as a "directory".  Is `super_secret_file.txt` a file or a directory?

Comment: The command line tool is `icacls`, not `icals`.

Comment: It is a file.  Thanks to you both, I got it situated.

Answer (score 1):

First remove everyone from permissions then give write permission again:

1. `icacls C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt /remove "Everyone"`
2. `icacls C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt /grant "Everyone:(w)"`

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
icacls C:\Users\Temp\super_secret_file.txt /grant "Everyone:(w)"
```